# Why to choose metadata navigation

Tags: managed-metadata, metadata

What is the difference between metadata navigation and filtering via column heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is the same idea, you navigate a term tree to get reach specific content. But metadata navigation (managed navigation) is more powerful in that that it allows you to navigate actual publishing pages as well as just list items, meaning that you can easily build for example an Organisation tree where each department can (automatically or manually) present themselves.

You could for example quite easily show the employees of an department (if that is in the User Profiles, in a managed metadata field).

Here is a guide to get you started: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2013-Navigation-using-Managed-Metadata-Term-Store.aspx

**Edit**

If you are refering to using Metadata navigation in a document library or list, then the difference is that you can more easily navigate the term hierarchy, particularly if it is a large one, and that you can easily see what node you have filtered on currently.

Comment: thanks Robert. My question was for document library only, thanks for clarification. So just user friendliness is the added advantage in using metadata navigation over colum heading. We can do all the stuff with column filtering as well, but its not that much user friendly. right..?

Comment: Very true, column header filtering is nice if you have multiple columns, but not as easy to use